# How start a single program within a new xserver instance in full screen mode?

Tags: linux, xorg, raspberry-pi, x-server

I'd like to run a program in full screen mode without the overhead of a desktop environment but simply on a xserver instance.

This is fairly easy by running:

```
startx <program>
```

Trouble is that that program gets placed in the upper left corner and I have no clue how to let it use the full screen height and width.

Any hints?

Comment: related: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/129367/dedicated-purpose-single-application-linux-boxes

Answer (score 3):

I implemented the next solution for start a single application with **xinit**, and I had the same problem that you, my solution was:

In **/etc/rc.local/** for example, I added the next line:

```
sudo su -l youruser -c "xinit -geometry =800x400+0+0 -fn 8x13 -j -fg white -bg black /home/youruser/bin/application -- -nocursor" &
```

My complete implementation of that in:

https://hpsaturn.com/raspberrypi-ascii-weather-station/

Answer (score 0):

Most X programs will accept the option "geometry" to state both window placement and size. This can also be set as an X resource. Usually the man page for the program will tell you which X resources you can set, or otherwise how to specify placement etc.

Other programs, such as Midori, will have a fullscreen option as an argument to the program:

```
midori -e Fullscreen
```

There is more information about options to Midori at [the midori website](http://midoribrowser.org/faqs/#always_open_midori_in_fullscreen).

Comment: Thanks for the answer but unfortunately [midori](http://midoribrowser.org/) does not support the geometry option.

Comment: It would have helped a lot if you'd said which program you were talking about from the start... I've now added information specific to Midori.

Comment: Well, which program I run doesn't matter too much. I've tried running midori -e Fullscreen without any success already, these options don't count if running a bare xserver without a desktop environment. The -geometry option was a good idea though, but midori doesn't implement it.

Comment: It would have mattered to me, as it would have saved me the time I spent writing an answer that does not apply to your situation. But I understand that this may not be of concern to **you**.

Comment: I appreciate your time and help. "-geometry" could have been a correct answer. So please let's don't make this a flame war.